# How to interchange/Transform the data in a plot to become the axes of a new plot.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology, graphing-functions, transformation

**TLDR: I have all values at each point on the p-h chart. I want to transform the data to obtain the T-s and h-s values from the p-h data**

I apologise if my framing of the question is not clear. It is because I do not know the terminology of what I want. I don't even know if it exists/can be done.

`Let me explain what I want to do.`

I have a dataset. It is the p-h curve's datapoints(pressure-enthalpy).
I want to transform the data in such a way so as to create the T-s (Temperature-entropy) curves from that data.

Abbreviations:

- P - Pressure
- T - Temperature
- v - specific Volume
- Q - Quality/dryness fraction
- h - sp.Enthalpy
- s - sp.Entropy

[image: This is the log(p) - h curve.]

I have all the data at each coordinate pair. (For any given point(p,h) on the plot, I have the values of T,S,v and inside the saturation dome, I also have Q).

Now i want to know if it is possible to transform that data in any way so that I can get the values of p,h,v,Q at any given point(T,s) in the  T-S chart.

[image: This is the T-s Chart.]

**I have all values at each point on the p-h chart. I want to transform the data to obtain the T-s and h-s values from the p-h data**

**Is it even possible??**

From the mathematics I remember from college and from 3blue1brown's videos, I know that the eigenvector is the vector that does not change when any transformation takes place. So, should I find the eigenvector of each of the values on this graph and then transform it somehow? How do I find the eigenvector? What transformations do I do? I don't know where to start.

**I do not even know the keywords to research my problem properly. I don't know which branch of mathematics this comes under**.

I am struggling with the tags to post this question under.

Any keywords/guidance will be **greatly appreciated**. I got the p-H datapoints using python. I want to use python to transform that data to T-S data.

For anyone who would like to see the tabular data, here it is.
Please note that this tabular data is only for points on the saturation lines(the thick black line that looks like a parabola).

[image: Saturation Values]

The below values are sample values of T,s and v at a few (p,h) points, not necessarily on the saturation lines.

[image: p-h table values]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [ +1 Interesting Question ] (A) If you know the relation(s) between P-H-T-S(-Q-V), you may be able to "transform" the Pictorial Display of the table. (B) There will be complications in case there are no 1-to-1 mappings at certain Points or even certain Areas. (C) It will be useful to include Partial table in the Post. (D) You may get better Answers in Physics Stack Exchange (E) Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors will be useful in later stages of analysis, but not in current stage.

Comment: @Prem, Thank you for replying. There are always 1-1 mappings for all points in p-h space and t-s space, but not in p-T space (you can see in the first chart that there are Temperature lines //el to the x-axis, constant pressure). I thought this would be a mathematics problem since It is about transformation of data. I will post it in other forums and see.

Comment: Oh ok, good to know that (B) is not a concern because there are 1-to-1 mappings. You have also considered (D) about Posting elsewhere. About (C), I want to reiterate that you should include Partial Data Points in the Post, maybe 15 or 30 rows of your table, which will also make us check (A) whether there are some nice relations between the variables & hence we can make it a Purely Mathematics Problem. When that is solved, we might also look into (E) when & where Eigenvalues & Eigenvectors might be useful here.

Comment: @Prem, I have added some tabular data. As far as I can see, there are no clear cut relations between the values.